# Getting values from a queue gives 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm trying to pass two variables to a thread using a queue and getting an error stating 'int' object not iterable.

First I tried putting 100 values inthe queue without threading, just to check I could put & get. This is the code (which works) to do that.

```
for i in range(100):
    spd,Dir=CalcSpeed()                 # Get speed and direction
    Speedqueue.put((spd,Dir))           # Put into the queue
    sleep(0.1)                          # Wait a bit before repeating
    UpdateBar(spd,Dir)                  # Update the graphics

for i in range(100):
    Spd,Dir=Speedqueue.get()            # De-queue item
    run_loop(Spd,Dir)                   # Run motor at required speed and direction
```

Then I moved onto the threading version and put the values in the queue like this:

```
if spd !=0:
    Speedqueue.put(spd,Direction)                    # Write both to queue
```

Then I try to recover the contents of the queue like this:

```
class Worker(Thread):

def __init__(self, queue):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.queue=queue    

def run(self):
    while True:

        if self.queue.empty():
            pass
        else:  
            Spd,Direction=self.queue.get()              # otherwise get results from queue

            last_Speed=Spd                              # and update last values
            lastDirection=Direction
```

When I reach the line to get the item off the queue, it all goes wrong. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You're using this to enqueue in the threaded version:

```
Speedqueue.put(spd,Direction)
```

which places a single item (`spd`) into the queue (`Direction` is presumably being interpreted as the `block` argument to `Queue.put`). In the preceding non-threaded version, you used:

```
Speedqueue.put((spd,Dir))
```

Here you're putting a *tuple* into the queue. In both cases, though, your dequeuing code is expecting a tuple to have been queued. When you attempt to assign multiple values from the `.get` result, python is assuming that the value is iterable in order to pull multiple values from it.

Summary: if you want to dequeue a tuple, you need to enqueue a tuple:

```
Speedqueue.put((spd, Direction))
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the different ways in which you pass things:

```
Speedqueue.put((spd,Dir))           # Put into the queue
```

You specifically do: `(spd, Dir)` to create a *tuple* with both elements and pass it as an argument.

When you go to the *threading* version:

```
if spd !=0:
    Speedqueue.put(spd,Direction)                    # Write both to queue
```

You are passing: `spd` as the 1st argument to `put` and `Direction` as the 2nd argument.

The signature of `put` is:

> Queue.put(item[, block[, timeout]])

See the docs (for 2.x but valid for 3.x): https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.put

Outside of a function call it is true that: `spd,Direction` will result in a tuple, but in this case each of the items is being interpreted as an item, and hence the actual thing being pushed into the *Queue* is: `spd` which is an `int` and not iterable. Therefore do:

```
if spd !=0:
    Speedqueue.put((spd,Direction))                    # Write both to queue
```

Comment: Ah! Of course. Why didn't I notice that? I still have lots to learn, but that's part of the fun I suppose.   Thanks for the help.

Comment: In that case you can accept either this answer or the one from Gil Hamilton (only one can be accepted, but both can be upvoted by yourself)